# Handling 24bit 96000Hz files with Pydub

Tags: python, pitch, pydub, 24-bit

I am impressed with `Pydub` pitch function. Tried a lot of pitch programmes but never could get a good result. Meaning with out echo ore hearing samples missing - short soundout fall, ore blurring sound.

Now I find out that `Pydub` is not able to handle `24bit/96000Hz HighRez wav` samples. And I am not willing to downsample my files.

Is there a way to get `Pydub` handle `24b/96` files?

Comment: The code is on GitHub, so that would be "yes".

Comment: @Bonifacio2 It sounds promising. I would very much like to get a clue what and how I can adapt to this code to get 24bit/96000Hz wav files working.

Comment: @Bonifacio2  I found the issue [https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/134] limitation is in the standard wave module